# edb-postgres unable to find record in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using edb-postgres database. There are numeric records assigned with a sequence in a table. The relevant column has a primary key feature. There is an oddity in 2000 records out of 70,000 records. Some records cannot return the result when I search as where column=value. But when I search for the same record with LIKE or sort by another column, I can see it. Why can't I find the relevant values when searching?

```
Index Scan using pk_tablename on tablename (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=63) (actual time=0.025..0.026 rows=0 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (id = '69239'::numeric)
Planning Time: 0.121 ms
Execution Time: 0.051 ms
```

Unsuccessful query:

```
select * from schemaname.tablename where id=69239;
```

Successful query:

```
select * from schemaname.tablename where id LIKE '69239';
```

Comment: This requires more information, such as the table definition, the queries, the indexes and the execution plans.

Comment: That's a query plan in the comment, but how should that give us any insight in why this query can't find some records? Records that you think should be found. And why do you cast an integer 69239 to a numeric value? In theory you could create a primary key as numeric, but it's something I have never seen the last 20 years.

Comment: I did not design the table, all of the primary key columns in the database are numeric, but is there a situation that will cause the query to be sent incorrectly?

Comment: Please also add the execution plan of the successful query.

Comment: Maybe the `id` was stored with some decimals. What does `where id >= 69239 and id < 69240` return? or maybe `where id::int = 69239`

Comment: The result of this query is also empty. Also, there is no problem when I dump the table and restore it in the test database. So there is no character problem in the value in the column.